# Excel Export JS Issue with Chrome - Dates in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, export-to-excel

I have encountered a peculiar issue with exporting an HTML table to Excel but only in Google Chrome. When I export the table, some of the values are interpreted as dates in Excel, even though they are not in date format in the HTML. This issue does not occur when using Safari.

Here's the code I'm using for the export:

```
function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
    // Create a new workbook
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    var dataSelez = jQuery('#ordine-datepicker').val();

    // Define custom sheet names in the desired order
    var sheetNames = [
        "TOTALE ORDINI",
        "STABILIMENTO A",
        "STABILIMENTO H",
        "STABILIMENTO C",
        "STABILIMENTO D",
        "STABILIMENTO E",
        "DETTAGLIO ORDINI"
    ];

    // Get all the tables by their class name
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll('.export-excel');
    // Iterate through each table and add them as sheets to the workbook
    tables.forEach(function (table, index) {
        var sheetName = sheetNames[index]; // Get the corresponding sheet name
        
        var newRow1 = document.createElement('tr');
        var newRow2 = document.createElement('tr');
        table.querySelector('tbody').insertBefore(newRow1, table.querySelector('tbody').firstChild);
        table.querySelector('tbody').insertBefore(newRow2, table.querySelector('tbody').firstChild);
        console.log(table);
        var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: sheetName });
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName);
    });

    // Export the entire workbook
    return dl ?
    /* XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }):
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || (dataSelez+'fileExcel.' + (type || 'xlsx'))); */
    XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64', mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' }) :
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || (dataSelez + '-fileExcel.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
 }
```

I've tried the following solutions without success:

1. Adding an apostrophe to the cell values.
2. Setting the mso-number-format attribute to "@".

Is there a known issue with Google Chrome's behavior when exporting HTML tables to Excel, or is there something specific in my code that I'm missing?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: extend `table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: sheetName })` to `table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: sheetName, raw: false })`, if not working you can try `table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: sheetName, raw: false, cellDates: false })` as is described here [Create a worksheet or workbook from a TABLE element](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities/html/#create-new-sheet). After that you can try your solutions with **mso-number-forma** and **apostrophe **

Comment: I tried both of the options, but unfortunately neither one of them works.

Comment: Let me ask, how did you do that? As described here [Styling Excel cells with mso-number-format CSS attribute](https://medium.com/@mrodz/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number-format-css-attribute-71d9da54edae)

Comment: I did this:
    table.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function (cell) {
        cell.setAttribute('mso-number-format', '"@"');
    });

Answer (score 0):

Prefix each cell value with an apostrophe (') to force Excel to treat it as text. You can modify your code like this:

```
// Iterate through each table and add them as sheets to the workbook
tables.forEach(function (table, index) {
var sheetName = sheetNames[index]; // Get the corresponding sheet name

var cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.textContent = "'" + cell.textContent;
});

var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: sheetName });
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName);
});
```

This should prevent Excel from interpreting the cell values as dates when you export the HTML table to Excel in Google Chrome.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it still doesn't work, now I still get a date but with an apostrophe (')